# golang google-bigquery v2 api to specify the destination table

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I am trying to using the google bigquery v2 api to run a query job and store the query resultset into another bigquery table, I did not find any doc or example on how to do it in the go wrapper of the v2 api. I can see there is a way to specify the destination table in the raw REST api payload, but need to make it working in the go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See documentation here [package bigquery](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/bigquery/v2)

Below is simple example. Hope this will give you right direction

```
import "google.golang.org/api/bigquery/v2"

bigqueryService, err := bigquery.New(oauthHttpClient)

if(err != nil) {
    return "ERROR"
}

var projectId = "your-project"
var datasetId = "your-dataset"
var tableId = "your-table"
var queryText = "your-query"
var writeDisposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"

job := &bigquery.Job{
    Configuration: &bigquery.JobConfiguration{
        Query: &bigquery.JobConfigurationQuery{
            DestinationTable: &bigquery.TableReference{
                DatasetId: datasetId,
                ProjectId: projectId,
                TableId:   tableId,
            },
            Query:    queryText,
            WriteDisposition: writeDisposition,
        },
    },
}

call := bigqueryService.Jobs.Insert(projectId, job)
job, err2 := call.Do()
if err2 != nil {
    return "ERROR"
}

//check job status
var jobid = job.JobReference.JobId
bqjob, err3 := bigqueryService.Jobs.Get(projectId, jobid).Do()
if(err3 != nil) {
    return "ERROR"
}
```